# MathJax: works in desktop browsers, but only when faking user-agent; works on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-platform, user-agent, mathjax

So, I've got this page (part of a Wordpress blog), 
http://gnuradio.org/blog/filtering-time-series-data__elemental-building-blocks/ , which *should* contain a rendering of my LaTeX formulas, exactly like:

[image: Firefox on Linux, pretending to have the User Agent string of an IPhone 3]

It does the same (works!) when I configure my Desktop's Firefox to pretend its user-agent was that of a Firefox running on Android

Sadly, without forcing my firefox to claim its user-agent string is that of an IPhone 3, the formula just never gets rendered; MathJax shows it's typical "initialization messages", but long before these appear, the "raw" LaTeX formula just disappears and never comes back rendered:

[image: Firefox on Linux, not pretending to be someone else]

Now, the peculiar thing is: It doesn't work with Chrome under Linux, either, and I've got a friend who reports the same problem with Safari/OS X but with Firefox on an Android device, it works [like a charm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7TTN.png).

Same goes for [Chrome on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxk6v.png).

So, I tried debugging things, but I haven't gotten beyond the following:

- Network requests seem to be identical, and so do the responses, no matter what user-agent I use on my desktop PC, aside from the fact that when things work, there's some traffic with cdn.mathjax.org (which is expected, as it loads webfonts)
- Putting a render job into Mathjax `Hub`'s `Queue` doesn't help either.

Not being a web dev at all, this is pretty much how far I've gotten. So both hints about what to poke at / use to debug this or definite answers solving my problem are equally welcome.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterKrautzberger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your page is loading code that modifies script elements in the page (`http://gnuradio.org/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/cloudflare/rocket.js`, which is titled `cloudflarejs-rocketloader-0.11.5` within the file.  It may be that cloudflare is adding this automatically without your knowledge, but the result is that the script elements in your page are no longer the standard script DOM elements implemented by the browser, but are a replacement implemented by this script.  Unfortunately, the behavior of the replacement is not identical to the original script elements, and that is causing MathJax to not be able to read the math (which is stores in script elements within the page).

You may be able to overcome that by adding

```
<script>
MathJax = {
  AuthorInit: function () {
    MathJax.HTML.getScript = function (node) {return node.textContent}
  }
};
</script>
```

to your page just *before* the script that loads MathJax.js itself.

Alternatively, try [disabling the full CloudFlare optimization](https://vxlabs.com/2014/09/30/cloudflare-full-optimizations-break-mathjax/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll discuss this with the person in charge of the infrastructure, and will report back; the first thing I realize about this is that *if* cloudflare is breaking things, they are probably over-optimizing the page. I started googling on cloudflare and mathjax; do you happen to have an opinion on the solution recommend [here](https://vxlabs.com/2014/09/30/cloudflare-full-optimizations-break-mathjax/), namely to disable the full optimizations?

Comment: So, the full optimization was disabled. I'm going to accept your answer, but will edit a "alternatively, disable full Cloudflare optimization", as that was what we did, and it worked.

Comment: "if cloudflare is breaking things, they are probably over-optimizing the page".  It's not really over-optimizing, it is that their implementation of the script tag is not fully compatible with what browsers do.  Of course, MathJax's code that uses the scripts was developed 8 years ago, and things were different then, so MathJax could be modernized to use the more current techniques (like the `textContent` that I suggested in my answer).  So MathJax's attempts to support older browsers is contributing to the problem.

Comment: I've edited the addition you made so that it links to the description that you found (since people may not read the comments when looking for this answer).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, adding that link was the right thing to do. Thanks for the technical insight - when I actually developed stuff for websites is a way back. I was really surprised to see <script>s that were not JavaScript...